# angular prepend `TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

## foreword

for learning purposes i wanted to create a tabs directive that can be used with a simple markup (based on custom elements, no ng-click or such, automatically generated tab-navigation).

---

## the problem

the basic setup was more or less easy and is working out fine, with one exception: when i want to **prepend** the automatically created tab-navigation using `.prepend(...)` i'll get the **following error thrown**: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined`.

a bit wired: the nav is generated and prepended as expected.

even more wired: using `.append(..)` works just fine - no error.

---

## so this is what i've done

1. create a template in the directive via `.run` and add it to the template-cache (i wanted to have all needed code in one file - *please don't punch me for that*)
2. collect all the tab-data from the markup needed for the navigation-template
3. compile the template
4. prepend it to the directive element

#### and this is what the compile- and prepend-code looks like

(nothing fancy, i guess)

```
// create and prepend the navigation
var $template = angular.element($templateCache.get('tabs/templates/tabNav.html'));
var $nav = $compile($template)($scope);

// throws error on local setup
// TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined
$element.prepend($nav);
```

for the whole setup please see http://plnkr.co/edit/yyTCoPQd4ld3w7kDDFCS?p=preview .

while i tried to reproduce the error using plunkr (just copied the whole shebang there), the error does not appear - wich is even more wired to me.

---

## my setup

- yo angular
- angular 1.3.15

please let me know if i'm missing any needed information - i'd be really grateful for any hint that helps me to figure this out.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876213/typeerror-cannot-read-property-childnodes-of-undefined-in-angularjs-directive) relevant to your current situation?

Comment: thanks for your help, i checked the solution, but it dosen't look like that's working for me, as i get the error no matter how often I use the tabs-directive.also the error does not appear when using `.append` instead of `.prepend`.