# Angularjs "Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined" on route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

There are a bunch of these very vague error questions on Stack, but none have been helpful for me here.

When I change routes (also going from one controller to another), I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined
    at nodeLinkFn (lib.min.js:8973)
    at compositeLinkFn (lib.min.js:8226)
    at nodeLinkFn (lib.min.js:8973)
    at compositeLinkFn (lib.min.js:8226)
    at publicLinkFn (lib.min.js:8106)
    at lib.min.js:8447
    at boundTranscludeFn (lib.min.js:8244)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (lib.min.js:9020)
    at update (lib.min.js:61060)
    at Scope.$broadcast (lib.min.js:17143)
```

One clue I had was from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876213/typeerror-cannot-read-property-childnodes-of-undefined-in-angularjs-directive), which suggests it might be because of duplicate elements being created.

I *do* have a template that is being loaded into both view1 and view2 (error ONLY occurs when going from view2 to view1; if I start at view1 then go to view2 it works fine, but if I go back to view1 from there it crashes).

I've removed the `widgets` template and the error doesn't break. But this template doesn't really do much at all (here it is in Jade):

```
section.widgets(layout="row", ng-if="widgets")
  md-card.widget(flex, layout="row")
    .left-panel
      .holder
        img.bar-graph(src="/img/bar-graph.png")
    .right-panel
      .right-contain  
        p.data-label Items Migrated
        p.datapoint {{widgets.items | number}}


  md-card.widget.left-margin(flex, layout="row", ng-if="widgets.users > 1")
    .left-panel
      .holder
        img.bar-graph(src="/img/bar-graph-2.png")
    .right-panel
      .right-contain
        p.data-label Users Migrated
        p.datapoint {{widgets.users | number}}

  md-card.widget.left-margin(flex, layout="row")
    .left-panel
      .holder
        img.bar-graph(src="/img/line-graph.png")
    .right-panel
      .right-contain
        p.data-label Data Migrated
        p.datapoint
          | {{widgets.data[0] | number}}
          span  {{widgets.data[1]}}

  md-card.widget.left-margin(flex, layout="row")
    .left-panel
      i.fa.fa-tachometer
    .right-panel
      .right-contain
        p.data-label Throughput
        p.datapoint 
          | {{widgets.throughput | number}}
          span  Mbps
```

What's going on here?!

Comment: Jascination, Can you share Plunker demo ?

Comment: @RayonDabre The app itself is quite complicated unfortunately.

Comment: @RayonDabre Do you have any clues on what this error actually means though?

Comment: I suppose you are using `angular-material`.. Have faced such issue earlier.. A nice little example will help me debug your situation...